# android exit application completely and go to main applications screen

Tags: android

i know that this question is asked many times, but really i can't understand the answer, i want to set button, when user click it i want to exit the application (also the carbage collector should remove the objects), and after exiting i want to go to the screen where the user found the application icon on mobile.

for exit i don't know what to do

for going to the screen where to find the application icon i tried like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

but doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this method, this will make your application to go in backgroud and will open home/app_menu screen

```
moveTaskToBack(true); //  method available in activity
```

[reference link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

When you start that activity, it will effectively stop your application's foreground activities. Android is designed to NOT shutdown the app so that it may be restarted faster.

However, if you really really want to purge the app from memory, then what you want to do is kill exit() on the Runtime singleton : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit(int)

Comment: and if i want to keep the activity in background? what should i do to just go to the screen where the icon of the application where?